# How to delete many line (serial) in text file using PHP?

Tags: php

I have I text file like this.

```
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E0_TDM1
channel=17-31
context=TRK3
group=0
channel=1-15
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E1_TDM2
channel=48-62
context=TRK3
group=1
channel=32-46
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E2_TDM3
channel=79-93
context=TRK3
group=2
channel=63-77
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
```

I want to delete 8 line begin with this line "context=TRK_E0_TDM".

The result I want is:

```
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E1_TDM2
channel=48-62
context=TRK3
group=1
channel=32-46
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E2_TDM3
channel=79-93
context=TRK3
group=2
channel=63-77
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
```

For easy to image, I have a picture below:
[image]

I write the PHP code, it can delete the specific line but I don't know how to delete a specific group.

It's mean:

- I want to delete group 1 and keep group 2&3
- Or I want to delete group 2 and keep group 1&3
- Or I want to delete group 3 and keep group 1&2

Thanks in advance.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$f = "trunk_e1.txt";

$term = "context=TRK_E0_TDM";

$arr = file($f);

foreach ($arr as $key=> $line) {

    //removing the line
    if(stristr($line,$term)!== false){
        unset($arr[$key]);
        break;
    }
}

//reindexing array
$arr = array_values($arr);

//writing to file
file_put_contents($f, implode($arr));
?>
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this, like copying the first valid lines to a new array and save that, find the line and index you want and slice the array, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution with `preg_replace` function:

```
$data = file_get_contents('trunk_e1.txt');
$result = preg_replace('/^.*context=TRK_E0_TDM.*(?=;\[Teca\-E1\]\s*context=TRK_E1_TDM2)/s', '', $data);
file_put_contents('trunk_e1.txt', $result);
```

---

Final `trunk_e1.txt` contents:

```
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E1_TDM2
channel=48-62
context=TRK3
group=1
channel=32-46
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E2_TDM3
channel=79-93
context=TRK3
group=2
channel=63-77
group=3
;cgoi=15v15r
;status=
```

---

**Bonus** extended solution for *dynamic* deletion:

```
$data = file_get_contents('empty.txt');
$group_id = 1;   // from 0 to ...
$pat = '/^(.*);\[Teca\-E1\]\s*context=TRK_E'. $group_id. '_TDM.*?(?=;\[Teca\-E1\]\s*context=TRK_|$)/s';
$result = preg_replace($pat, '$1', $data);
file_put_contents('empty.txt', $result);
```

Comment: but I have i problem. How can I delete ;[Teca-E1] context=TRK_E1_TDM1 ........ ----> ;status= after detere ;[Teca-E1]
context=TRK_E0_TDM???

Comment: @NguyễnTrầnThanhLâm, if you have new conditions - you should add it to your question. When it will be done, let me know

Comment: It worked,  I cant delete group 1 and keep group 2&3, but I can't delete group 2 and keep group 1&3. Or I can't delete group 3 and keep group 1&2. :(

Comment: I edit my question, again, I think my question not clearly for you. Could you read it and help me :D

Comment: @NguyễnTrầnThanhLâm, my solution gives the expected result. What do you want from me?

Comment: I know, it worked, but I want  this: "

    I can delete group 1 and keep group 2&3

    Or I can to delete group 2 and keep group 1&3

    Or I cant to delete group 3 and keep group 1&2".

Comment: @NguyễnTrầnThanhLâm, you got my last update, bonus solution for you. Enjoy